# android facebook-foursquare style header

Tags: android

I want to implement a header which has gradient background and a right icon, as is facebook & foursquared android apps. I couldn't find any tutorials about this.

I looked into foursquared source code but couldn't find how they implement this. If you can show me a way to implement this in that foursquare source code, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at GreenDroid https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid.

Comment: thank a lot! greendroid includes everything i needed. it's a kind of three20 replacement which we use in ios platform.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a custom component that consist of a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` where you set the background of it to your gradient color, and then just add the desired components of the header as `child views` of your layout.
Then include this layout in all your activities layout at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) app source code. They build an action bar using a style.

Here's the layout for the home activity:
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/activity_home.xml

Here's the include for the action bar:
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/actionbar.xml

Here is the style that defines the action bar:
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/values/styles.xml